# Qual o comando para cortar papel na Bematech MP-2100 TH?

Tags: impressora

Qual o comando para cortar papel na Bematech MP-2100 TH?

Vejam que não é a FI ela é não fiscal, na internet acha facil quando é fiscal.

Tentei #27+#119 mas não aceita

Comment: https://youtu.be/w9hVPYLbHo8?t=100

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a [documentação da própria Bematech](http://partners.bematech.com.br/bemacast/Paginas/post.aspx?idPost=5806):

> Os modelos de minimpressoras da Bematech que possuem este recurso são: MP-2100 TH, MP-4000 TH e os lançamentos MP-4200 TH e MP-2500 TH. Ambas possuem o mesmo comando para acionamento da guilhotina.

Como você não citou a linguagem de programação que está utilizando, vou colocar o exemplo em *Delphi*.

`function ComandoTX( BufTrans: string; TamBufTrans: integer ): integer; stdcall; far; external 'MP2032.DLL'; function AcionaGuilhotina( Modo: integer ): integer; stdcall; far; external 'MP2032.DLL'`

`//ACIONAMENTO DA GUILHOTINA sComando := #27 + #119; iRetorno := ComandoTX( sComando, Length( sComando );`